# How to make a user enter 5 marks into a 2D array?

Tags: java

**I need to create a program that allows a user to input marks for 
     assessments.
     I have my code here but my output display is incorrect. I am not sure where 
     im going wrong.
     This is what i have done so far**

```
 public class Vetting{
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   String TeacherName;
   int RatesArray[][] = new int [5][5];

int Assessment1,Assessment2,Assessment3,Assessment4,Assessment5;

      public int [][] RateArray()
      {   
       for(int row =0; row<RatesArray.length;row++)
      {

       for(int col = 0; col<RatesArray.length;col++)
       {

           RatesArray[row][col] = input.nextInt();
       }
   }

   return RatesArray;
   }

 public void OutputArray()
   {
       RateArray();
      System.out.println("The rates are: ");
       System.out.println("\t\t Assessment1, Assessment2, Assessment3, 
       Assessment4, Assessment5");

           System.out.println(" ");

           System.out.println("Student 1: \t");
           System.out.println("Student 2: \t");
           System.out.println("Student 3: \t");
           System.out.println("Student 4: \t");
           System.out.println("Student 5: \t");
       for(int row = 0; row<RatesArray.length;row++)
       {
            for(int col = 0; col<RatesArray.length;col++)
           {

               System.out.print(RatesArray[row][col] +"\t");
           }

           System.out.println("\n");

       }

   }
```

**This is my output**
[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nglmm.png)

**This is how it should have been**
[The correct way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIOMy.png)

i will appreciate any help i could get 
Thank you

Comment: What you're trying to do is to "scroll up" on the terminal and print over lines where you've already printed the headers. That's not typically done in Java, but it's quite possible using a library such as [charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva).

Comment: I will have a look through that.. Many thanks

Comment: @einpoklum It's not necessary using an external library for printing a simple formatted table to terminal

Comment: @0x1C1B: The problem is printing _over_ what's already been printed before, rather than adding printed lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove below lines

```
 System.out.println("Student 1: \t");
 System.out.println("Student 2: \t");
 System.out.println("Student 3: \t");
 System.out.println("Student 4: \t");
 System.out.println("Student 5: \t");
```

problem: you printing the student on different lines and later you printing the marks so 
Just move student counter to for loop

```
 for(int row = 0; row<RatesArray.length;row++)
       {
          System.out.print("Student "+(row+1)+": \t");//changes here
            for(int col = 0; col<RatesArray.length;col++)
           {

               System.out.print(RatesArray[row][col] +"\t");
           }

           System.out.println("\n");

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this version it should print a valid table...

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int [][] array = new int [5][5];

for(int studentIndex = 0; studentIndex < array.length; ++studentIndex)
{
    for(int gradeIndex = 0; gradeIndex < array[0].length; ++gradeIndex)
    {
        array[studentIndex][gradeIndex] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
}

// Prints table with headers

System.out.format("%20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%n", "", "Assesment 1", "Assesment 2", "Assesment 3",
            "Assesment 4", "Assesment 5");

for(int studentIndex = 0; studentIndex < array.length; ++studentIndex)
{
    System.out.format("%-20s", "Student " + studentIndex);

    for(int gradeIndex = 0; gradeIndex < array[0].length; ++gradeIndex)
    {
        System.out.format("%-20d", array[studentIndex][gradeIndex]);
    }

    System.out.format("%n");
}
```

By the way the main problem with your code is, that it print all row headers first with a newline! You need to print row by row... Every row with it's own row header and it's values! Moreover you need to print a newline only after one row is finished...

```
First row:  Student 0    5    7    5    1    2 -> Newline only here
Second row: Student 1    5    2    8    3    7 -> Newline only here
...
```